# Django function that checking new alerts in DB

Tags: python, django, postgresql, notifications

I will start my first django project in  my collage and I want to know how can I make a function that checking every x time or when I have a new row in the "alerts" table DB and after send email or sms to the user.

My project is web system monitor.

Comment: This does not look like something to do with the database, but with a queue system like rabbit-mq. This is designed for asynchronous tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `cron jobs`, with `cron jobs` it's possible to do an action every while, in a periodic manner.

To create `cron jobs` in django you have to create a `custom django-admin command`.

- In one of your app create a folder `management`, and in `management` folder create another folder `commands`
- In `commands` folder create a file `my_costum_command.py`. It's the name of the command that will appear in list of `manage.py` commands. (the app must be in installed apps)
- import the libraries and models you need to check the database

  `from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand`
- Then, create a class like :

  ```
  class Command(BaseCommand):
      help = 'Description of the command'
      def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
      # your code for the action (checking database)
      # check the database and send email if needs
  ```

Now, the command will be executed from `manage.py`

Then, create a cron jobs and execute the command every while like (here every hour):

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 * * * * /home/mysite/venv/bin/python /home/mysite/mysite/manage.py my_custom_command
```

Here is the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#command-objects) How to create a custom django-admin command